# Service com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver has leaked ServiceConnection JobServiceConnection that was originally bound here

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I see this exception pretty often in my logs with my OnePlus 6 on Android 10 (API level 29) :

```
E/ActivityThread: Service com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver has leaked ServiceConnection com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobServiceConnection@46c1fc8 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver has leaked ServiceConnection com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobServiceConnection@46c1fc8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1820)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcherCommon(LoadedApk.java:1692)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1671)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1755)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1684)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:705)
        at com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ExecutionDelegator.tryBindingToJobService(ExecutionDelegator.java:155)
        at com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ExecutionDelegator.executeJob(ExecutionDelegator.java:132)
        at com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayMessageHandler.handleStartMessage(GooglePlayMessageHandler.java:98)
        at com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayMessageHandler.handleMessage(GooglePlayMessageHandler.java:67)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I also see this warning following the exception:

> FJD.ExternalReceiver: Error unbinding service: Service not registered:
> com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobServiceConnection

Has anyone experienced this ? Any idea how to fix this please ?

EDIT: this issue seems related to the firebase-jobdispatcher lib:
https://github.com/googlearchive/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/157

which is closed, but I still see the exception with version 0.8.6 of the lib